# Get auth_request module working where proxy_pass returns 302

Tags: nginx, module, auth-request

This our setup:
- We got React app running on nginx which needs to be secured on endpoint AAA
- When user try access AAA, i am trying to do proxy_pass to site BBB.

auth_request module expects endpoint BBB to return 200 (for success) and 401 for error. The trouble is BBB is full blown Enterprise SSO website and it is trying to return response 302 and with Location being CCC (where user needs to enter his/her credentials).

How can get proxy_pass command to show that redirected page to user so that credentials can be entered ?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am having the same issue.

Comment: nopes, had to implement SSO differently so that we get user credentails and then pass it on to the webservice (which is being used by corporate websso login page).